# Git push to live server through limited ssh

Tags: git, codeigniter, ssh, shared-hosting

I'm using GitHub to keep track of my source code. Although I work alone, it comes really handy to test new features and rollback if it doesn't work. So, I installed in Git Bash in my windows machine, and commit & push to github when the code is ready.

Now, I want to take this further and deploy from the same terminal. My shared-hosting has SSH access but is kinda limited. They told me they had Git, but only as a client, to read repos. I don't know what that means.

I was trying to make a repo on the live server, add it as remote on my machine and then just 'git push remote live' but that didn't work.

Whenever I type 'git init' on the live server it returns:

```
warning: templates not found /usr/share//git-core/templates/

Initialized empty Git repository in /www/example.com.ar/htdocs/example.com.ar/.git/
```

And I can't 'git clone' or 'git pull' or anything!

Is there any tips you can give me? I'm just tired of drag&dropping my folder via FTP, it just feels so wrong!

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

GitHub is the git server

Both you and your hosting will simply act as clients.

all you need to do (if git is properly installed) log into your ssh session.

type the following into the terminal

```
git clone git://github.com/<username>/<name of repo>.git folder_name
```

to clone that git repo into `folder_name`

to get updates you have pushed to the live server, you need to again, log into ssh and `git pull`

Comment: Thanks @jondavidjohn! I was able to clone my repo to my server, it just grabs the files on github and put it on my live server. However, when my repo gets updated, I've tried to 'git pull' on the server, and it throws an error. Maybe you can tell me what it is (BTW git version 1.5.2.2):/usr/bin/git-parse-remote: line 58: sed: command not found
/usr/bin/git-ls-remote: line 30: expr: command not found
fatal: protocol error: expected sha/ref, got 'ERR
  Your Git client has made an invalid request:
  0027 /fedeisas/GPS.git'
Cannot get the repository state from git://github.com/fedeisas/GPS.git

Comment: 1.5.2.2 is really old. A lot has changed since then. The Git user manual itself is currently written for 1.5.3 or newer. You should just install the latest version of Git. You don't even need root access to do so (i.e. it will install to your home directory by default).

Answer (score 2):

This is how I do it:

http://philsturgeon.co.uk/news/2010/02/Deploying-websites-with-Git

Comment: Can't belive my CI hero notice my question! I've read that post in my previous research, and that's exactly what I was trying to do. After a couple of emails with my hosting, it turns out they had a BAD install of Git, missing lots of packages, and they refuse to reinstall those packages because I might be doing some dangerous stuff with their servers. Too bad my client won't let me pick another hosting service. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 1):

There is a git server that'll handle incoming git requests so you don't need to access it via SSH. It's not very popular (relative to just the client) and you don't need it. The git client should be all you need. It sounds like there is something else wrong with their install.

Perhaps someone else can chime in here and get git working in this limited environment for you, but when there are so many dirt cheap and really flexible hosts out there it's probably much easier to switch to one of them and solve a whole gamut of problems all in one.

Dreamhost, MediaTemple, RackspaceCloud, Slicehost, and (of course) Amazon EC2 are just a few of solid hosting services worth checking out.

Comment: Thanks men! Yes, I know there are lots of hosting services with much more features than mine, but I'm just working for a client that has all this sites (it's a design agency) on that hosting. I don't think they're gonna change it because 'the lazy programmer' said so. How can I know if they have that 'git server that'll handle incoming git requests' installed? Thanks!

Comment: Well it sounds like they told you they don't, and since it's unlikely they would be running it, I think it's safe to assume.

Comment: git --version : git version 1.5.2.2
At least, they've installed git. Maybe they corrupt their installation on purpose?